# Customizing Android Progress bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to style android progress bar as shown below which have multiple sections in it.

[image]

Which properties need to be changed for that?

Here is my custom xml file.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape>
  <corners android:radius="5dip" />
  <gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:centerColor="@color/customeprogresscolor"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:endColor="@color/customeprogresscolor"
    android:startColor="@color/customeprogresscolor" />
</shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
<clip>
  <shape>
    <solid android:color="@color/yellowCadmiumLight"/>
  </shape>
</clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I would rather use a custom view that extends `ProgressBar` and customize the `ondraw` methiod where you can draw sqaures on canvas

Comment: Is there any other way you are aware of to do that?

Comment: multiple view in linear layout with an orientation of horizontal, in your case 9 view that are squares.